# itext - pdf checkbox filled differently

Tags: pdf, checkbox, itext, pdf-generation

I have a pdf fillbale form with a checkbox in it. If i use the acrobat reader, the checkbox is filled like this
[image: checkbox filled by acrobat]

but, if i use itext 5.5.13, the checkbox is filled like the the one below.
[image: checkbox filled by itext]

the way the checkbox filled is different across acrobat and itext. is there a way to make the itext fill the checkbox similar to acrobat and make it bold.

I'm using the following code to fill the checkbox.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();

form.setField("cb1", "Yes");

stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
stamper.close();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Some hint is given here: https://developers.itextpdf.com/de/node/2503

Comment: Thank you Lonzak. Is there a way in itext to change the real appearance of the checkbox field, so that it appears like the X mark in the first image

Answer (score 1):

You can change the appearance of a checkbox with the /AP key. In the case of a checkbox, you'll find two appearance states (On, Off) under the normal appearance (/N). These XObjects define what you see when the PDF is rendered.
So if you want to change that, you have to define your own apperance. Have a look at the following [class](https://github.com/msnoigrs/iText-LGPL-MPL-fork/blob/master/src/core/com/lowagie/text/pdf/RadioCheckField.java) especially at the `getAppearance()` method. After creation you can set it with the following code:

```
PdfAppearance tpon = getAppearance(isRadio, true);
PdfAppearance tpoff = getAppearance(isRadio, false);
field.setAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, onValue, tpon);
field.setAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, "Off", tpoff);
field.setAppearanceState(checked ? onValue : "Off");
```

Comment: Thanks again Lonzak. i will try the method you mentioned.